# ToolTip отображает криво посказку

Tags: c#, winforms

Приветствую всех. Такая вот проблема, ToolTip отображает подсказку, где-то в стороне от компонента, [скрин](http://i54.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0329/8f/78d5020203fc9c72e40d1d924716d08f.jpg). Но после повторного нажатия кнопки, он встает на свое место, [скрин](http://i51.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0329/fc/b4e243583daa95d19c23fba78f3eb6fc.jpg). В чем может быть проблема, почему он сразу не отображает где надо?

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске, давайте код. (Только не весь проект, а лишь нужный кусок.)

Comment: catch            
{
toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Ошибка";
toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 100;
toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
toolTip1.Show("Не выбран год", this.comboBox1);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch
{
    toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Ошибка";
    toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
    toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 100;
    toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
    comboBox1.Focus();
    toolTip1.Show("", this.comboBox1);
    toolTip1.Show("Не выбран год", this.comboBox1);
}
```

Вот, решил проблему таким путем. Добавив `comboBox1.Focus();` и `toolTip1.Show("", this.comboBox1);`. Через одно место, но зато сразу выводит на контроле.